# Control access to files available for download

Tags: php, zend-framework, .htaccess, zend-controller

I have a folder that contains uploaded documents that my ZF application can spit out to logged in users. I want them to be able to use a link like `http://server/documents/filename.pdf` and download the file, but I want to have a controller `DocumentsController` that enables the existing user cookies to verify that they are logged in and have permission to download the file. I don't want to have to use URLs like `http://server/documents/index/id/1` if I don't have to, though its not a terrible option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use X-SendFile to obtain the best performance. It is supported by Apache (mod_xsendfile), Lighttpd and Nginx. The request is first handled by a php process which put a special header (X-Sendfile or X-Accel-Redirect for Nginx) and when the script end, the web server take over and send the file like a static file. It is faster and use less memory.

To redirect all the request to your controller, you need to write a custom route in your bootstrap :

```
protected function _initRouter()
{
    $router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();

    $documentRoute = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route(
        'document/:filename',
        array(
            'action'     => 'xsendfile',
            'controller' => 'documents'
        ),
        array(
            'filename' => '\..+$'
        )
    );
    $router->addRoute('document', $documentRoute );

    return $router;
}
```

You can use this action helper to handle the x-sendfile header : http://www.zfsnippets.com/snippets/view/id/27 and you need to had code to check if the user is authenticated.

Comment: This sounds great. I'll give it a try and let you know!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use [Zend_Acl](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.acl.html) to control access to the `DocumentsController` and then create [custom route](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html) to redirect `http://server/documents/*` to `http://server/documents/index/id/*`.

#### Edit:

The [solution proposed by Tomáš](http://blog.red-pill.cz/2007/03/06/zabezpecene-stahovani-souboru/) will work better for bigger files.