# Upload files to a folder that only logged in users can read php

Tags: php, file, upload

Hi i have a problem with making a safe upload folder in a project.

The thing is that we have a file upload that everyone should be able to upload files to, but only the site administrator the site should be able to view the files later.

Is it possible making a folder non readable, but accessible from a php page?

The server is a linux inviroment

Comment: possible duplicate of [Restrict file access to authorized php users](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/738500/restrict-file-access-to-authorized-php-users)

Comment: Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5813350/allow-logged-in-user-to-download-file-in-php-else-nobody-cant and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858018/control-access-to-files-available-for-download

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually several ways to do this.

1. Apache configuration (you may restrict access to certain directory by IP security, or HTTP authorization), see: [allow,deny](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html) and  [apache authentification](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/howto/auth.html)
2. Save files to directory which is not accessible via website and write your own php directory listing and file download, via [readfile](http://sk.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)
3. Upload file to directory which will be accessible only via "secret" ftp/sftp.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer to this is to place the files in a directory outside your web root, and built a page to view the directory that requires an administrator auth to access.

If the files are outside your web root, they cannot be directly accessed with a `/path/to/file.ext` type URL.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, I would locate the folder outside the document root, or restrict it's access via Apache directives.

Then, using the PHP and checking access credentials, output the file using [readfile()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Here is an example from the manual
<?php
$file = 'outside/root/monkey.gif';

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```